# Is this ERD correct?

Tags: sql

[image: ERD]

This ERD is part of my school work and something doesn't seem right. The ERD table 'Course' looks like its referencing 2 tables. Is the column titled 'Qual_Code' in table 'Course' from the 'Prerequisite' table, the 'Qualification' table or both? I don't think its both because you cannot have a single column with a foreign key that references two different tables.
Help because I have to write the SQL codes for this!

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first glance, it appears that the column qual_code of the COURSE table is redundant.  When writing the DDL code for this, you can include or exclude this column -  see the following examples:

[course table with qual_code column](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f1567fca900186554ad3c9bb81efa613)

[course table without qual_code column](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=901447bb9b707cb16e6245ce20f342b0)

The PREREQUISITE table maps courses to qualifications.  The PK constraint in this table will not allow NULLs in either of the columns ie if a row gets INSERTed, it must contain values for both course_num and qual_code.

> I don't think its both because you cannot have a single column with a
> foreign key that references two different tables.

It seems that you are misinterpreting this.  The PK column of the QUALIFICATION table is referenced twice (FK columns reference a PK or UNIQUE column, not the other way round -> see the DDL code on DBfiddle).